# Testing Nested Error Handling with OCMock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, mocking

I'd really appreciate some advice around testing for errors using OCMock.

**Method Under Test**

It grabs a process using an instance of the AppScriptController class.

```
@implementation ProcessGrabber

  -(void)grabProcess {
      NSError *error = nil;

      NSString *processName = [appScriptController processName:ProcessRef
                                                         error:&error];
      if(error == nil) {
         NSNumber *processID = [appScriptController processID:ProcessRef
                                                        error:&error];

          if(error == nil) {
          ... More operations...
          }
      }

      if(error) {
          [NSApp raiseError:error];
      }
  }

@end
```

**Method to Mock**

The AppScriptController class interacts with the system, so I want to mock it out.

```
@implementation AppScriptController

-(NSString *)processName:(SERef *)theProcessRef error:(NSError **)theError {
    return [[theProcessRef name] error:error];
}

-(NSNumber *)processID:(SERef *)theProcessRef error:(NSError **)theError {
    return [[theProcessRef name] error:error];
}
```

**The Test**

```
-(void)testGrabProcess {
  NSError *error = nil;        

  OCMockObject *mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[AppScriptController class]];
  [[[mock expect] andReturn:@"Process Name"] processName:nil error:&error];

  // ... Somehow inject an error here...

  [[[mock expect] andReturn:34] processID:nil error:&error];

}
```

**The Problem**

I want to check the nested error handling code works correctly. So I want to be able to inject a specific error code at a specific point in the method.

**Examples**

Simulate an error in the process name grabbing. I'd test that the process ID grabbing doesn't get called.

Simulate an error only in the process ID grabbing. I'd test that the process Name grabbing is run, but no operations after process ID are executed.

No matter where the error occurs, test that the correct error is raised.

**What I've tried**

The obvious thing to try is to set the error where I've put "...Somehow inject an error in here...". I didn't expect this to work, and it didn't.

I've searched on Google for answers and I've thought about trying to somehow wrap the error in a seperate class, but I can't see how this would help.

I've thought about this for hours, but I'm still no nearer to a solution.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd love to seen an actual test method with real test code, as I feel something is getting lost in the the simplification of the question.  That said, perhaps OCMock isn't the best tool for the job, here?  I'm not so sure it handles `NSError **` parameters very well (I've never tried).  Perhaps you'd be better served by using a custom [test stub](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Stub.html), rather than a generic mock object?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to post the code as it's pretty poor and convoluted right now - too much so for other people to read.

However, I've tried to implement my own custom test mock, and it was far easier than I thought it would be. That's solved the problem for me - my custom mock is now working like a dream, so thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: See @dariaa answer below RE: OCMock "isn't the best tool". It CAN be done using OCMock

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else is still looking for this, there is in fact a rather simple way to do it with `OCMock`:

```
- (void)testGrabProcess {

    OCMockObject *mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[AppScriptController class]];
    [[[[mock expect] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        NSError * __autoreleasing *anError = nil;
        [invocation getArgument:&anError atIndex:3];
        *anError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MYDomain" code:2323 userInfo:nil];
    }] andReturn:@"Process Name"] processName:nil error:&error];

    [[[mock expect] andReturnValue:@34] processID:nil error:(BECloudPlayerDevice *__autoreleasing *)[OCMArg anyPointer]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another test for the case of returning nil;

```
-(void)testGrabProcessError {
  NSError *error = //create the error code you want to test here.;        

  OCMockObject *mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[AppScriptController class]];
  [[[mock expect] andReturn:nil] processName:nil error:&error];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, that's the obvious way of doing it when you have one mock object. 

I've not articulated my problem correctly in my question - sorry about that. My problem is that I have 3 or 4 mocks in the test, all of which are passed the error. 

I need to inject the error **between** mocks, so that I can test nested error handling.

I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I thought it was a bit obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

Having a method in MyClass like this:

```
- (BOOL) myMethod:(id)someParameter error:(NSError **)error;
```

In the test I do this:

```
id myMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyClass class]];
[[myMock expect] myMethod:someParameter error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)[OCMArg anyPointer]];
```

And this way I avoid creating a custom mock subclass of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for **OCMock 3** syntax:

```
    AppScriptController *controller = OCMClassMock([AppScriptController class]);
    OCMStub([controller processName:[OCMArg any] error:[OCMArg setTo:nil]]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        NSError * __autoreleasing *err = nil;
        [invocation getArgument:&err atIndex:3];
        *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:123 userInfo:nil];
    });
```